# Calculating the standard deviation of a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want the user to provide a string. The string will be divided into individual characters. Each character will be put into a number (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, etc) and then put into an array with the values, and then the standard deviation will be calculated.

I already have the code to convert the letters:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length ; ++i ) {
    // 'A' unicode value is 65, so by substracting 64 you'll get 1 for A, 2 for B, 3 for C...
    total += [str characterAtIndex:i] - 64;
```

But that code only uses the string (maybe there is a way to just put the values directly into a string?)

And the code for standard deviation:

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @2];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:numbers]]];
NSNumber *value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@,", value);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how would I convert string of letters to array of numbers?

Comment: Add each number to an array instead of incrementing `total`.

Comment: Are you trying to see "how close" one string is to another? if so I don't think this is going to get you what you want. Are you looking to duplicate a soundex https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 or levenshtien https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance kind of algorithm?

Comment: FYI - Avoid the hardcoded `64`. Use `[str characterAtIndex:i] - 'A' + 1`. Of course your whole approach only makes sense if the string only has the uppercase letters A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how would I convert the string of letters into an array of numbers?", try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:str.length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[str characterAtIndex:i]-64]];
}
```

Comment: Simpler: `[array addObject:@([str characterAtIndex:i]-64)];` Note you can't use `str[i]`.

Comment: oops. I was thinking arrays.

Comment: It's also important to note that the array members are `NSNumber`s, not integers, so they have to be converted if you want to look at them directly, i.e. `array[i].intValue`.